# What does the 'T' in a datetime refer to? I.e. the 'T' in 2014-05-30T11:20:16

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, datetime-format

An asmx service that I am consuming contains a datetime with a 'T' in it. I.e. `2014-05-30T11:20:16`. What does the T refer to? GMT?

Comment: GMT (or UTC) would be referenced by a `Z` at the end, or by a `+00:00` offset at the end.  With neither, there is no context provided.  It will parse to a `DateTime` with `.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  You should be careful about the time zone context in how you use this value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Per W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime):

> [..] the "T" appears literally in the string, to indicate the beginning of the time element, as specified in ISO 8601.

Comment: +1 for source doc, not really sure why this answer has been downvoted

Answer (score 4):

It's a separator to disambiguate between the date and time components.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that the Time part of the `DateTime` object has started from here.

```
2014-05-30T11:20:16
```